# MongoDB: sorting only the items that is less than or equal to a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm looking for a way to sort only the documents where their `count` is 0 to last, but preserve the regular order for the rest of the query.

```
item: { 
    name: String,
    count: Number
}
```

is this possible with MongoDB aggregation?

Comment: Sort by which field? And when you sort only docs with `count` is 0 naturally regular order will be changed.

Comment: If you don't specify a sort when querying MongoDB, the order of the returned documents in undefined.

Comment: @MuratColyaran this is the case where I want to put ALL of the documents with their `count = 0` to last, but not sort for any other items. Effectively, if an item's `count` is 0, put them at the last of the query

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want is in 4 steps:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
await client.connect();
const db = client.db("MyDb"); // Your db name

// Step 1 get count=0 records from item collection
const countZeroRecords = await db.collection('item').find({ count: { $eq: 0 } }).toArray();

// Step 2 create a new collection for count=0 items
await db.createCollection("countZeroItems");

// Step 3 insert items to the new collection
await db.collection("countZeroItems").insertMany(countZeroRecords);

// Step 4 create index
await db.collection("countZeroItems").createIndex({ "name": 1 });
```